# What does "arrange to dispatch" mean? Does it express multiple things of action?

Tags: meaning

Complete sentence:

> Pls find the attached New PO for Feb 2019 requirement for your reference, Kindly arrange to dispatch 5K for tomorrow and remaining by 10th of Feb 2019.

PO = Purchase Order

Answer (score 2):

*Arrange to dispatch* means **to meet the requirements/prepare for transfer** (of something, e.g. "*5K*").
The transferring itself is implied as well, but technically not part of the 'arranging'.

**It can express multiple actions**, since it implies that one takes care of *whatever needs to be done* (the requirements) for the dispatch (the transferring, sending, or mailing).
Taking the mailing of an item as an example, it needs to be properly packaged, the complete address of the receiver needs to be clearly indicated on the parcel, it needs to be passed on to a post order company, the sending needs to paid for, &c.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My dad runs the business; he was given a purchase order and calls were not received later. He didn't send invoice; though he could have, at the end of completion of work of manufacturing carton boxes. Buyer later didn't receive calls, and we are not paid for the made work. To be said, my dad seems to have not consciously understood the meaning and took actions; though he completed the work but could not send it from buyer not receiving calls. I am writing a email now, thought on asking on this here now.

Answer (score 1):

It will be inappropriate to write "Please dispatch..." to say the Head of Dispatch section. Instead "arrange to dispatch" possibly means "take appropriate steps to have the item dispatched..." 
"Arrange to dispatch" is frequently used in Indian offices. It may mean "steps to ensure dispatch..."

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My dad runs the business; he was given a purchase order and calls were not received later. He didn't send invoice; though he could have, at the end of completion of work of manufacturing carton boxes. Buyer later didn't receive calls, and we are not paid for the made work. To be said, my dad seems to have not consciously understood the meaning and took  actions; though he completed the work but could not send it from buyer not receiving calls and later no replies in email. I am writing an email now saying on MSME Samadhan portal, thought on asking on this here now.